# CakePHP redirect to previous URL after login

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.2.0, When a user is not logged in, when a link is clicked, it goes to the login page, after login i would like to redirect to the initial link that was clicked. Anybody knows how we can implement it using CakePHP? I tried with the `$this->referer()` but it seems not getting the previously visited URL. If anybody knows please help me to sort out!

Answer (score 17):

If you need to redirect to the referer page you can use:

```
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```

Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#flow-control

Comment: I have tried with the referer as like above but it always getting '/' in the referer even though we came from other pages. Is there any other methods to do this ?

Comment: You maybe check something like this: `public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',    
        ), This maybe is the reason after login, always to return other link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..  i have the following lines in my before Filter function in my controller, $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login','plugin' => false); 
  $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller','Actions'); 
  $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;

Comment: Is it not possible to add the referer redirection with the above loginAction ?

Comment: By using `$this->redirect($this->referer());`, I think CakePHP automatic redirection, we don't need add any `loginAction` yet.

Comment: Okay.. if i want to change the login action to a new controller called clients and action name is login2 then i would use the above like $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'clients','action' => 'login2','plugin' => false); in that situation if i didn't use the loginAction then it will redirected to the /users/login. What should i do in that situation ? i have to change the login action to /clients/login2 and also need the referer redirection. Is there any way to do both ?

Answer (score 5):

In the method processing the login, you could redirect to

```
$this->Auth->redirectUrl()
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
if ( $this->Auth->login() ) {
    return $this->redirect( $this->Auth->redirect() );
}
```

From the [doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in):

> The above code (without any data passed to the login method), will
>   attempt to log a user in using the POST data, and if successful
>   redirect the user to either the last page they were visiting, or
>   AuthComponent::$loginRedirect. If the login is unsuccessful, a flash
>   message is set.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {

    $this->Session->write('SESSION_DATA_HERE', 1);
    return $this->redirect( $this->Auth->redirect() );      
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash("Username or Password is incorrect.Please try again.", 'error');

    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Validate Auth User, if tru then redirect to the last visit page otherwise to the login screen from which user logged in by providing username and password

Comment: Tested in cakePHP 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do this by adding some `back_url` to your **Log In** link and then you can use that value for redirecting users.

Something like this:

```
<?php
// log in link 
echo $this->Html->link('Log In', '/login?back_url='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 

// log in action
$back_url = $this->request->query('back_url');
if($back_url === null) $back_url = '/';

// ... some other code

if($this->Auth->login()) {
   $this->redirect($back_url);
}
?>
```

Comment: While this would technically work, it introduces huge maintenance overhead by requiring updates to _every single link_ that points to the application. What if a 3rd party links to your webpage and you can't update those links? The optimal solution (see the ones above) wouldn't require changes to all links, but rather just the login function itself.